# Spring Boot and Keycloak configuration in properties raise a NullPointerException then 500 status code

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, keycloak

I am currently working on a project and I have to deal with Spring Boot and keycloak.
I want a configuration that is in the application.properties of spring.
Here is a part of my configuration file:

```
keycloak.enabled = true
keycloak.auth-server-url=${SSO_URL:http://MYIP:8082/auth/}
keycloak.realm=${SSO_REALM:approfox-dev}
keycloak.resource=${SSO_CLIENT:approfox-dev-login}
keycloak.ssl-required=none
keycloak.public-client=true
keycloak.principal-attribute=preferred_username
```

But when I try to access to any API endpoint, I got an 500 Internal Server Error with juste a NullPointerException. I do not know from where or why this exception occures. It seems that the application properties file is not loading by keycloak because when I use keycloack.json and the method that load it, it works.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@KeycloakConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
@ConditionalOnProperty(
    value = "keycloak.enabled",
    havingValue = "true",
    matchIfMissing = false
)
class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        SimpleAuthorityMapper grantedAuthorityMapper = new SimpleAuthorityMapper();
        grantedAuthorityMapper.setPrefix("ROLE_");

        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(grantedAuthorityMapper);
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }
    @Bean
    @Override
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(HttpSessionManager.class)
    protected HttpSessionManager httpSessionManager() {
        return new HttpSessionManager();
    }

    // Keycloak Spring Boot resolver not working
    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(
                new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.csrf()
                .disable()
                .cors()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/exemple1")
                .hasRole("student")
                .antMatchers("/exemple2")
                .hasRole("admin")
                .anyRequest()
                .permitAll();
    }



    // keycloak.json working...
    /**
     * Overrides default keycloak config resolver behaviour (/WEB-INF/keycloak.json) by a simple mechanism.
     * <p>
     * This example loads other-keycloak.json when the parameter use.other is set to true, e.g.:
     * {@code ./gradlew bootRun -Duse.other=true}
     *
     * @return keycloak config resolver
     */
    /*@Bean
    public KeycloakConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakConfigResolver() {

            private KeycloakDeployment keycloakDeployment;

            @Override
            public KeycloakDeployment resolve(HttpFacade.Request facade) {
                if (keycloakDeployment != null) {
                    return keycloakDeployment;
                }

                String path = "/keycloak.json";
                InputStream configInputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);

                if (configInputStream == null) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Could not load Keycloak deployment info: " + path);
                } else {
                    keycloakDeployment = KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(configInputStream);
                }

                return keycloakDeployment;
            }
        };
    }*/
}
```

I have searched all over internet I can't find anything about that issue...

My POM.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxxx</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>xxxx</name>
    <description>xxxx</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.18</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
<!--            <plugin>-->
<!--                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>-->
<!--                <version>3.1.1</version>-->
<!--                <configuration>-->
<!--                    <descriptorRefs>-->
<!--                        <descriptorRef>project</descriptorRef>-->
<!--                    </descriptorRefs>-->
<!--                </configuration>-->
<!--                <executions>-->
<!--                    <execution>-->
<!--                        <id>make-assembly</id>-->
<!--                        <phase>package</phase>-->
<!--                        <goals>-->
<!--                            <goal>single</goal>-->
<!--                        </goals>-->
<!--                    </execution>-->
<!--                </executions>-->
<!--            </plugin>-->
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: I see you have keycloak-spring-boot-starter 8.0.1 and keycloak-adapter-bom version 3.3.0.Final. I think you should specify same version for both as shown in the [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_spring_boot_adapter).  I think you need to skip keycloak-spring-boot-adapter